# Why is Astora's Straight Sword so bad?

Tags: dark-souls

I actually had to grind 14 Faith to be able to use the Astora's Straight Sword. I was super disappointed when my attacks were doing 29 damage with <kbd>R1</kbd>. I have a Drake Sword that does 200 damage per hit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue isn't so much with the Astora's sword, but the Drake sword.

[It's a Trap! The Drake Sword and you](http://www.destructoid.com/blogs/Nic+Rowen/it-039-s-a-trap-the-drake-sword-and-you-dark-souls-blog--230463.phtml)

You need more than faith for the sword, since it will have other stats for scaling, but I recommend the above article so you build your character properly for the late game.

Comment: actually I'm not sure.
I have a test account with maxed stats. I have astora's strait sword +5 with max str dex and faith. Yet it only has 423 attack raiting. With a maxed account you can make most weapons in the game enchanted +5 and they have +500 attack rating. Making this one of the weakest weapons in the game. Also I was trying to use it against skeletons in the catacombs and it was only doing 29 damage. Isn't this supposed to do bonus damage vs skeletons?

Comment: @user2656801 There's always a better weapon. The choice of which one you choose might not be dependant on stats, but play style, or even just what looks cool. What Nelson is pointing out however, is that players can get "tricked" by early OP weapons, like the Drake Sword, which are OP early game, but if your character is levelled correctly, is completely outmatched by even a longsword with correctly balanced stats